# Scala: How to compute the sum of all elements in the leaves of a Binary Tree?

Tags: scala, sum, binary-tree, immutability, case-class

I'm learning Scala by working the exercises from the book "Scala for the Impatient". Given the following way to model binary trees with `case` classes, one question asks to **compute the sum of all elements in the leaves**.

```
sealed abstract class BinaryTree
case class Leaf(value: Int) extends BinaryTree
case class Node(left: BinaryTree, right: BinaryTree) extends BinaryTree
```

My solution is as follows and works as expected. However, I'm using a `MutableList` and because Scala favors immutability, I am wondering **if there's a way to solve the problem using `List`**?

```
def leafSum(tree: BinaryTree): Int = {
  collectLeaves(tree) { MutableList[Int]() }.sum
}

private def collectLeaves(tree: BinaryTree)(leaves: MutableList[Int]): MutableList[Int] = tree match {
  case Node(left, right) =>
      collectLeaves(left)(leaves); collectLeaves(right)(leaves)
  case Leaf(value) => leaves += value
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning a `MutableList` when you want an `Int`?  You don't gain anything from doing the sum later; just do it right there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a List is not a good idea for the reason that when you concatenate two lists, you will have to copy their content so an O(n) complexity operation each time you encounter a Node.

If you really want to do it with Lists, you could do it like this:

```
def leafSum(tree: BinaryTree): Int = {
  collectLeaves(tree).sum
}

private def collectLeaves(tree: BinaryTree): List[Int] = tree match {
  case Node(left, right) => collectLeaves(left) ::: collectLeaves(right)
  case Leaf(value) => List(value)
}
```

although in my opinion it's better to compute directly the sum as you don't need to store the values in the leaves:

```
def sum(tree: BinaryTree): Int = tree match {
  case Node(left, right) => sum(left) + sum(right)
  case Leaf(value) => value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recursive approach that doesn't use a helper method that I think is fairly elegant. Note it's not tail recursive and will run out of memory for large inputs.

```
def leafSum(tree: BinaryTree): Int = tree match{
  case leaf:Leaf => leaf.value
  case node:Node => leafSum(node.left) + leafSum(node.right)
}
```